# Wrapping Bufferreader around Scanner is efficient?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream, bufferedreader, coding-efficiency

Since there's the discussion which is more efficient, I've seen some code wraps input this way:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(input);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(buff);
```

I'm just learning about i/o in Java and seems like some programmers prefer Scanner (to use for primitive vars) while others prefer BufferedReader (and read as String)

Is the inserted code efficient or is the same as just using Scanner in one line?

Please explain with details considering my apprentice status

Comment: Besides the fact that there are different methods already asked, does the wrapping give any benefit?

Comment: As in the linked duplicate, wrapping _buffers_ the input - which may be faster. Further, it allows you to set the character encoding, which is very important.

Comment: I guess that Im still understanding the benefits of buffering the input (and character encoding). I'll keep investigating.